# Step functions vs piecewise continiuty

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, piecewise-continuity, step-function

**Definition**: A function $f :[a, b] \Rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said to be **piece-wise continuous** if there exists a partition $a = t_{0} < t_{1} <...<t_m =b $, such that for each $k$, the restriction of $f$ to the open interval $(t_k,t_{k+1})$ is continuous, and extends to a continuous function in the closed interval $[t_k ,t_k + 1 ]$.

**Definition**: A function $g: [a, b] → R$ is called a **step function** if there exists a partition $(t_0, t_1, t_2,..., t_m)$ of $[a, b]$, and numbers $(c_0, c_1, c_2, ..., c_m)$, such that $g(x) = c$ for $t_j< x <t_{j+1}$, $j = 0,1,2,..., m - 1.$ In other words g is constant on each open interval $(t_{j} ,t_{j+1})$.

My question:

Considering and comparing of two these definitons can we say that step functions are piecewise continious on the closed intervals?

P.S.

as mentioned on the coment by @copper.hat "The only question here is if the constant functions can be extended to a continuous function on the closed interval". But in my opinion it is not so diffucult. Just we can define limit values to the end points.

Comment: what are your ideas?

Comment: The only question here is if the constant functions can be extended to a continuous function on the closed interval.

Comment: @copper.hat Technically there is also the question of whether constant functions are continuous. A solution on a test wouldn't get full marks by me if they didn't say at least something to the effect of "we know that constant functions are continuous". I don't think they would need to prove it, but it should be pointed out.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you for reply. I didn't see any difficulty to do it, in my opinion.

Comment: @copper.hat I will add your comment to my question.

Comment: @Arthur for full mark I will ad your comment too

Answer (score 1):

(I'm unable to add to the thread as I don't yet have rep 50 :P)

> But in my opinion it is not so diffucult. Just we can define limit values to the end points.

An implicit part of your definition of piece-wise continuous is that the subfunctions, $f_k$, you have for each interval $[t_k, t_{k+1}]$ must agree on endpoints i.e.

$$f_{k}(t_{k+1}) = f_{k+1}(t_{k+1})$$

So consider what happens to these endpoints on a generic step function

Comment: Thank you for answer, I didn't think so, definition doesn't consider subfuctions must agree on endpoints. It just says every subfunction can be extended to the continous function on closed interval itself

Comment: Each partition is a restriction of $f$ so we want an extension which agrees with $f$ right? Thus each subfunction on each interval must have extension which agrees with the adjacent subfunction on the end points (because they each have to agree with $f$)

Comment: E.g. if $f(x) = x^2$ and we consider $[0,1]$ and partition this with $0=t_0<0.5=t_1<t_2=1$ then we have the sub functions $f_1,f_2$ which are defined as the restriction of $f$ on $(0,0.5)$ and $(0.5,1)$ respectively. We need these to continuously extend to agree with f on their endpoints and so we need $f_1(0.5)=f_2(0.5)=f(0.5)$
If you're specifically wanting this to NOT be true then you are not defining piece-wise continuous in the same way that it is widely known and likely result in problems elsewhere.

Comment: I cite to the book's definition, it doesn't mean every subfunction must agree on the endpoints. It just says every subfunction can be extended to the continious function in the specified closed subinterval. It is like removable discontiniuty

Comment: We don't want an extension agree with f. In other words by piecewise function meant a function with finitely many discontiniuties

Comment: Could I ask, what is this purpose of this? What is the book or what is the book about? Seems a little pointless to have the rest of the definition and not to include a condition like this as it means you can't use it for much without having this as a separate definition as well as not lining up with other textbook definitions? I wonder if this is a typo?

Comment: The book I am reading fundamental mathematical analysis by robert magnus. Can I ask you question too??  Do you consider "floor function" as piecewise continious???

Comment: I personally wouldn't however, if the book does then go with the book. It just seems odd to me but I'm sure the book has its reasons

Comment: It doesn't follow from the definition that $f_k(t_{k+1}) = f_{k+1}(t_{k+1})$. If this would be the case, every piecewise-continuous function would be continuous. Maybe you are confusing piecewise-continuous with piecewise-$C^1$?